# @ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-decoupled-document does not render properly with ReacJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ckeditor

When I try to load CKEditor using DecoupledDocument build, it does not render "the document". Instead, it just takes the background

**CKEditorDocument.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { CKEditor } from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-react';
import DecoupledEditor from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-decoupled-document';

export default function CKEditorDocument() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h2>Using CKEditor 5 build in React</h2>
      <CKEditor
        editor={DecoupledEditor}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

**package.json**

```
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-decoupled-document": "^35.4.0",
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-react": "^5.0.6",
```

the result i want
https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/examples/builds/document-editor.html

Answer (score 0):

```
import React from 'react';
import { CKEditor } from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-react';
import DecoupledEditor from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-decoupled-document';

export default function CKEditorDocument() {
    return (
        <div className='App'>
            <h2>Using CKEditor 5 build in React</h2>
            <CKEditor
                //just add this line
                onReady={(editor) => {
                    console.log('Editor is ready to use!', editor);
                    editor.ui.getEditableElement().parentElement.insertBefore(editor.ui.view.toolbar.element, editor.ui.getEditableElement());
                }}
                //---------//
                editor={DecoupledEditor}
            />
        </div>
    );
}
```